What formula will count the number of words in a cell, ignoring dashes and other standalone punctuation?
I need to count the words in each cell of a table. There’s no built-in wordcount function, so I’ve previously used a couple of methods that effectively count the number of spaces, adding 1 to get the correct total. But this is inadequate since my text often includes dashes as punctuation which get counted as extra words.
A complication is that if two words are joined by a hyphen without whitespace, they should be counted as a single word, so I don’t just want to treat all hyphens as whitespace in a solution.
What formula can accurately count the number of words in a cell?

After some experimentation, I’ve come up with the following formula which uses the countmatches() function to count the number of words, as defined by a regular expression in the regexp() function:
=countmatches(C2, regex("[\w'’-]+"))

Rather than counting spaces, this counts words made up of any sequence of characters which includes alphanumeric characters (\w), apostrophes (either smart or “dumb”), and hyphens. Since a hyphen is replaced with an em-dash when used as standalone punctuation, this happily doesn’t wrongly count those as words either. It should be easily extendable to include other characters as necessary.
